# Visual Basic close a form when windows default border has been removed

Tags: vb.net, window

I am using Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2019. I have made a word processor and that is working fine, but now I am trying to get rid of the windows default border and make my own close button.

I have been using this in the past when my windows default border was still there:

```
 Me.Close
```

The error that keeps coming up is:

> Property access must assign to the property or use its value.

Thank you.

Comment: Does `Me.Close()` get hit when you click that button? The *default border has been deleted* means you have set `FormBorderStyle = None`? If that's all, `Me.Close()` does what it's supposed to do. Unless you have some `e.Cancel` condition in `FormClosing()`. Or something is blocking/awaiting at that point.

Comment: There is no e.Cancel in my project and yes I do use Me.Close when the button is pressed. I have set FormBorderStyle = False.

Comment: `FormBorderStyle = False` doesn't exist. That property accepts a `FormBorderStyle` enumerator, not a boolean. I didn't ask you whether you have used `Me.Close()`, I asked you whether a BreakPoint set on `Me.Close()` is hit while debugging.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `End`.
It closes every windows and stops the application.

Comment: `Application.End` does way more than that.

Comment: This is bad practice.  Stopping your program using `end` is like stopping your car by driving it into a brick wall.

Comment: If `End` is not a good way to solve it do you have any other suggestions?